# What is the meaning of Borg names?

Tags: star-trek, borg

With a few exceptions, Borg drones are usually named `X of Y`, where X and Y are numbers. But what does that mean? I am especially interested in understanding what the latter part implies.

- Does the "of Y" part always refer to other drones, or to something else (Like: 4 of 6 meaning "4th drone of ship 6")
- How are the drones in the same number pool (Say, the other 8 people sharing the surname "of Nine") "related"? Do they work on the same stuff, or are they also more closely connected? I think I remember a Voyager episode where they were forming some kind of subcollective, but I can't remember if this was the norm or not
- Are these individual designations? Given the sheer amount of borg drones, I would expect names more in the ballpark of "50.312 of 101.2342", yet the names we see all are one-digit integers.

Since I am pretty sure (I might be wrong though) that the naming is not addressed in any of the series or movies, I would also accept explanations from novels or games.

Comment: Those designators may be a small part of an elaborate identification, but the only part that reasonably translates into English.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47154/borg-naming-conventions https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/16490/what-does-seven-and-nine-mean-in-seven-of-nine

Answer (score 23):

## Those names are job titles.

Seven of Nine's full name is "Seven of Nine, Tertiary Adjunct of Unimatrix 01."

Unimatrix means a large group of Borg with 01 being the Borg queen's group of Borg, and tertiary adjunct is a job title basically meaning the third helper.

So, she's the seventh of a group of nine drones, with the job of a third helper in Unimatrix one. These titles are flexible, and they can change as a Borg changes their roles.

They also have unique identifiers. Seven of Nine's is 108.44236000. From Timeless.

> "For the record, Seven's translink frequency is one zero eight point four four two three six zero zero zero."

Comment: Why would "translink frequency" refer to an identifier? Surely that's the frequency of their built-in communicator?

Comment: Because it's used as a unique way to call just her.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, and I am willing to accept this as an answer should no other explanation come up. Though I always found it odd that, if these numbers are supposed to be exchangable identifiers describing their job, it's treated like a name (especially in case of Seven). Should I ever wake up out of this matrix, I would prefer _not_ to be called "Engineer of CorpXY"

Comment: The borg don't really care about individualism, and so names aren't that important to them. If you need to address an individual drone you use their translink frequency, their phone number basically, and the names just serve for identification in small groups.

Comment: The whole point of this naming style is that Borg drones aren't individuals and lack singular identities, so their "names" aren't really suitable for the purpose by human standards. Seven choosing to maintain the last designation she held is an act of resisting assimilation (by humans).

An illustrative comparison might be to the Unsullied in Game of Thrones. These are slave soldiers who randomly draw new (dehumanizing) names by lot every day. When freed, some choose to keep the name they held on that day, even insulting ones like "Grey Worm". In that case, it's a matter of reclamation.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The analogy is IP address.

Comment: @Spencer a MAC address, or even a hardware serial number, might be a better analogy given that IP addresses are relatively mutable but it’s implied that translink frequencies are not.

Comment: @Philipp These are Borg. They are not like you. That's the point.

Comment: I've always wondered why it's "3rd of 5" but "7 of 9".  He had an ordinal number while hers was cardinal.  Shouldn't it be "7th of 9" to be consistent?  Granted it's probably just because that's harder to say, and with her being a major regular character, and them figuring everyone would forget about Hugh's few appearances way back in the day 2 entire series earlier, they chose the name that rolls off the tongue a bit less awkwardly.

Comment: Seems to me that the Borg queen should be on Unimatrix 00.

Comment: How do we know that she's the seventh drone of a group of nine, as opposed to the seventh drone in the 9th group?

Comment: Because we've met two three and four of nine from her original group.

Comment: Unimatrix zero isn't an official unimatrix. Unofficially it's where the rebel borg live, and the borg queen isn't a rebel.

Comment: @NepeneNep: I think fredsbend's point was that we'd expect the queen to start her numbering at 00, like a normal computer addressing scheme.  Some programming languages can index arrays starting with 1 as the first element, but under the hood it's typically 0, as in 0 elements past the start.  But perhaps like IP addresses, 00 is reserved for a special meaning in the addressing scheme, e.g. if you can sent to 00 to send a message to all unimatrixes instead of a specific one.

Comment: The borg queen isn't actually human, so I wouldn't expect her to follow a normal human computer addressing scheme. She was a member of Species 125, and the leader of an alien race called the borg.

Comment: @N.Virgo We've also to my knowledge never met a Borg whose first number is larger than their second, which would presumably happen frequently if it were X drone of Y group.

Answer (score 8):

The first such name shown is Hugh's, in the TNG episode "I, Borg". When Geordi asks for a way to refer to him - with Hugh initially unclear on the concept - he eventually says that he is "Third of Five". Geordi connects this to the five Borg crewing the crashed scout ship where they found him.

So, these are not so much names as the equivalent of when you place a large online order and it arrives in multiple packages labeled 1/3, 2/3, 3/3, or like when you get a numbered ticket when joining a queue. They're almost certainly not unique, except in so far as the Borg may rarely use them internally, so a specific identifier like "Seven of Nine" might only refer to one person because the other seventh members of nine-drone groups don't ever get referred to individually like that.

Comment: In "I, Borg", Hugh is asked if he has "a name, a means of identification", to which he immediately responds with "third of five". We can't infer much more from that other than that this _is_ a means of identification for them. Crucially, we do not learn the _meaning_ behind this means of identification, which is what I am asking for in this question.

Comment: ...and Geordi immediately connects the "five" to the crew of the scout ship, clearly communicating that the name means "he was the third member of a crew of five". That is the plain meaning of the exchange: the closest thing Hugh has to an identifier is a description of his membership in a smaller sub-group of Borg, which is linked to a (probably temporary) grouping of drones for a specific mission. There's nothing I'm aware of to suggest a deeper or more complex meaning than this clear one.

Comment: No, that's not really what happens, and the distinction is crucial: Geordi _asks_ if the number refers to the number of borg on the ship, but he doesn't get an answer. Hugh himself implies later on that the numbers are some kind of designation, but it doesn't get any more specific than that. The only information we can glean from that episode is: 1) It's a designation of some kind, 2) Geordi assumes it has something to do with the number of borg .

Comment: Geordi does not ask him if the number refers to the ship. He *observes* that there were five on the ship, then asks if that's the only available identifier: https://youtu.be/e_etbhWJoMo

We are shown that the only identifier this drone can think to offer is a number that a character points out corresponds to the size of the group he was found with. The meaning of that is straightforwardly obvious. The episode is telling us something simple and not being coy about it. You could invent alternate interpretations if you wish but there's no reason I can see to do so.

Comment: I do not dispute that it is an identifier. Both your and Geordi's observation is the easiest one available in "I, Hugh". But the lore about the Borg has expanded after this, and so has the information we have available about the meaning behind the names. The other answer raised that there is another identifier available per drone. A Voy episode establishes that in one case, the drones carrying the same "surname" have been interconnected.  So I am looking for more information about the naming scheme beyond what was already surfaced here. It might not exist though.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you have put so far in your response and our discussion, @Amanadiel .